# C programming: Read all ascii characters from stdin

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I'm having trouble finding a way to write a program that's able to read all the ASCII characters (including the non-printing characters and white spaces) from stdin.
I know scanf doesn't work for whitespace characters (not sure about other non-printing characters).
Basically I'd like to put the whole file into an array, containing everything from the original text file (stdin = .txt file).
Does anyone know how I could do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

read up on `getchar()` to get "all ascii characters". Also `fgetc(stdin)`.

To write to files you will need to use `FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode) function, fputc(int c, FILE *stream), fclose(FILE *)`

Comment: `fgetc(stdin)` is same as `getchar()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char buf[16]; 
  int c; 
  while (c=fread(buf,1,16,stdin)) 
    fwrite(buf,1,c,stdout);
}
```